# Change where basket saves notebooks?

Tags: encryption, storage, truecrypt, preferences

Currently I am trying to use Basket but, I can't find the place where it lets me change where my Baskets are stored. I need to keep them encrypted from prying eyes and want them located in `/media/truecrypt1`. I've searched all the menus and settings to no avail.

Comment: What options do you have when you click in *Settings*?

Comment: It gives me the settings for shortcuts, toolbars, and basket notes. When I click on the basket notes one it give me the tabs; general, new noites, baskets, notes apperance, applications.

Comment: It seems to store them all in `~/.kde/basket/baskets/` but, I can't change this directory :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. All the notes are saved in that folder in Kubuntu. And in Ubuntu, they are saved in `~/.kde/share/apps/basket/baskets`.

There is no option to save all the futures notes created in a specific folder.

Alternatively, you can **export** all the notes that you want to, in any folder or external device. To do that, do a second-click in the note and select *Export* -> *Basket archive...*

[image: screenshoot]

---

I have requested this feature sending an email to the developers, but this project seems to be abandoned. Hopefully, some programmers will improve this software so we can have this feature in a future release of basket :)

Comment: Thanks, it's a shame it's abandoned, it's wonderful except for the fact that you can't encrypt the whole basket and it's sub baskets with one click and this issue. :(

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can change the default location (at least in version 2.0 beta).

http://basket.kde.org/screenshots.php

If you have a folder already:
...go to Basket > Bakup and restore > Use another existing folder

If you want to move a folder 
...go to Basket > Bakup and restore > Move to another folder